# X forwarding: Disable secondary monitor

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, cygwin, xorg, xforwarding

I use X forwarding from a linux box to a windows box (X forwarding) which has 2 monitors.
New windows are always opened at the opposity display.
Thats so terribly annoying!

Any way to get rid of this behavior?

I searched a lot but without success. I don't even know which part is really responsible for the mess (cygwin, linux box, the individual application(s)) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your remote display setting is something similar to `hostname:0`, right?  Have you tried `hostname:0.1` (note the appended ".1")? Back in the day, the `.x` was supposed to indicate the display number on the X device (but, who knows whether it still works that way).

I'd suggest trying `:0.0` or `:0.1` or similar and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( - it is set to: $:~> echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0

Comment: In that case, try localhost:10.1 instead.

Comment: I also tried that - changing to different xx.y combinations. E.g.: "Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.1".

Comment: Meh... I was afraid of that.  Oh well, it was worth a shot.